# How to recall FETCH API whenever my Server Side Component loads

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I want to fetch the data again in my server side component in Next.js whenever a component loads (just like API calling in `useEffect` when using client side component)

Currently only when I refresh the page, then the API is called again.

Here's my API calling code

```js
const garageData = await fetch(
  `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL}users`,
  {
    cache: 'no-store',
    next: { tags: ['user'] },
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${data?.jwtToken}`,
    },
  }
);

return garageData;
```

I have set the cache to 'no-store' but still its not calling API again when I route to this page via router or Link.

I am calling API  in my component like this

```
const Home = async () => {
  const data = await getData();

  return <div>Home</div>;
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: `const data = await getData();` is invalid since `Home` isn't declared an `async` function. On top of this React components ***can't*** be async, they must ***always*** return valid JSX. A Promise object isn't JSX.

Answer (score 0):

The [useEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect) hook is what you want.

Anything that happens in the component function body before the return gets called first on the server (one time) then on the client every time the component re-renders.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const Home = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
       // client side code goes here
       // runs only once on the client after Nextjs finishes hydrating
       const data = await getData();
    }, []);

    return <div>Home</div>;
};

export default Home;
```